# Haskell package missing c library

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I'm having trouble building the [hmatrix library](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix) on OS X Lion. Looking at the .cabal file, it requires the `gsl` library, so I installed it with macports. The .a files are in /opt/local/lib and the .h files are in /opt/local/include/gsl

As suggested [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-February/003456.html)  I changed the built-type from Custom to Simple.  (without that change I get a similar error).

When I use `cabal configure` I get the following output:

```
* Missing C library: gsl
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

So I tried `cabal --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib configure`, but I still get the same error.  I can compile and link a c program that includes gsl.  What files is cabal looking for?  If I have the right files, how do I tell it how to find them?

libgsl.a is a universal binary:

```
$ file /opt/local/lib/libgsl.a
    /opt/local/lib/libgsl.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
    /opt/local/lib/libgsl.a (for architecture x86_64):  current ar archive random library
    /opt/local/lib/libgsl.a (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
```

ghc looks like it's 64-bit:

```
$ ghc --info
 [("Project name","The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System")
 ,("GCC extra via C opts"," -fwrapv")
 ,("C compiler command","/usr/bin/llvm-gcc")
 ,("C compiler flags"," -m64 -fno-stack-protector  -m64")
 ,("ar command","/usr/bin/ar")
 ,("ar flags","clqs")
 ,("ar supports at file","NO")
 ,("touch command","touch")
 ,("dllwrap command","/bin/false")
 ,("windres command","/bin/false")
 ,("perl command","/usr/bin/perl")
 ,("target os","OSDarwin")
 ,("target arch","ArchX86_64")
 ,("target word size","8")
 ,("target has GNU nonexec stack","False")
 ,("target has subsections via symbols","True")
 ,("Project version","7.4.2")
 ,("Booter version","7.4.2")
 ,("Stage","2")
 ,("Build platform","x86_64-apple-darwin")
 ,("Host platform","x86_64-apple-darwin")
 ,("Target platform","x86_64-apple-darwin")
 ,("Have interpreter","YES")
 ,("Object splitting supported","NO")
 ,("Have native code generator","YES")
 ,("Support SMP","YES")
 ,("Unregisterised","NO")
 ,("Tables next to code","YES")
 ,("RTS ways","l debug  thr thr_debug thr_l thr_p  dyn debug_dyn thr_dyn thr_debug_dyn")
 ,("Leading underscore","YES")
 ,("Debug on","False")
 ,("LibDir","/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.4.2/lib/ghc-7.4.2")
 ,("Global Package DB","/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.4.2/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d")
 ,("Gcc Linker flags","[\"-m64\"]")
 ,("Ld Linker flags","[\"-arch\",\"x86_64\"]")
 ]
```

Comment: Complete shot in the dark: do you have g++ installed? I remember installing a different library and getting similar weird error messages (it was also not finding C libraries that were clearly installed); it later turned out that it also needed g++.

Comment: I do have g++ installed.

Comment: Have you tried `cabal install -v hmatrix` to see the step that fails?  It might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @JohnL That worked...  I was trying to install nix as suggested below and I was having trouble with the C compiler not being able to create executables.  On my path was a version of gcc 4.8 I was playing with awhile ago.  So in the terminal with gcc 4.2 on the path first, I tried `cabal install -v hmatrix` and it worked.

Comment: @usmcs glad you got it fixed.  I would have been guessing for quite a while before checking the gcc version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to mac-ports you can use the [nix](http://nixos.org/nix/) package manager for mac.  It does a pretty good job of taking care of the c dependancies for for the libraries available through it. In general I have been more happy with it then any other package manager on mac.

Unfortunately mac(darwin) unlike for linux does not have as many binaries available through nix so installing ghc often means waiting for it to compile.

The commands to install ghc and hmatrix after installation of nix are:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs-unstable.haskellPackages.ghc
nix-env -iA nixpkgs-unstable.haskellPackages.hmatrix
```

All of the needed dependencies will be taken care of for you.

I just tried it on my macbook pro and hmatrix seems to be working correctly in ghci after trying commands from the first few pages of the [tutorial](http://dis.um.es/profesores/alberto/material/hmatrix.pdf).

Comment: I didn't end up using nix but when I tried to build it, I discovered the discrepancy with the versions of gcc I was using.  This definitely lead me to the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a mac person, but it really sounds like you haven't installed the "-dev" version. For a mac, I suspect you need to install `gsl-devel` in addition to `gsl`. If the problem persists, verify that you have `libgsl0-dev` on your library path.

Comment: I did install the -dev version with `port install gsl-devel +universal`.  I'll check the libgsl0-dev location.

Comment: I don't have libgsl0-dev anywhere on my system.  What makes this different than libgsl?

Comment: Hmmm. Do you have any filename of the form `libgsl?-dev`? I don't know if the `0` in `libgsl0-dev` is important or not, but I think the `-dev` bit is. Generally you need the `-dev` version of a library to do any development against it. Maybe something went wrong with the installation of `gsl-devel`.